# Git not cleaning garbage

Tags: git

My local repo is huge! but when I do a fresh clone its only ~5GB

When I run

```
$ git count-objects -vH
```

I get

```
warning: garbage found: .git/objects/pack/pack_git2_a00484
[many lines like this]
warning: garbage found: .git/objects/pack/pack_git2_c11896
count: 0
size: 0 bytes
in-pack: 38993
packs: 4
size-pack: 1.28 GiB
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 206
size-garbage: 42.19 GiB
```

and

```
git fsck --full --unreachable
```

Is showing lots of unreachable commits and blobs

I've tried many different commands including

```
git repack -Ad
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

but nothing is actually getting cleaned up.

How can I clean up my current repo to be the same as a fresh clone?

Comment: "Only" 5 GB? That's pretty huge. Have you considered [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/)?

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of the one marked, and I've clearly stated that I've tried the answers given in the duplicate and they didn't work for me. But lets not anger the Q&A Nazis.

Comment: And yes at some point we will be adopting git-lfs, but first we need to get a server that can run it

Comment: SO to the rescue, right? This is clearly not actually a duplicate and Google marks this as the top answer ... so there's that. @DontPanic345, did you ever get an answer?

Comment: Sorry @Jaime I don't think I ever did get a solution. I just pushed all my branches, deleted the whole local repo and cloned it again.

Answer (score 0):

How about [git prune](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune). (e.g. `git prune -v`)